# Remote control Pandora iPhone app from Mac

Tags: iphone, remote-control

I'm trying to replace my Sonos system with old iphones. I can stream Pandora with the iphone app but also want to be able to control the music remotely from my Mac.
Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a VNC app that will allow you to remote control your mac. Something like "Screens" https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-client-for-ios/id400012962?mt=8

That will allow you to control your mac entirely from your iDevice.

Comment: I want to control the iphone from my Mac ...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use an iPhone as a VNC server... provided it's jailbroken. There's a post [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remote-control-iphone-computer/) that talks about it and goes through installing and setting up one such app, named Veency.

Answer (score 1):

[Remoteless for Pandora](http://remoteless.no/pandora/index.html) is a remote iPhone / iPad app that lets you remote control Pandora running in Safari, Chrome or Firefox.